# html option data show going outside

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to get `<option>` beside product name field but `<option>` while information getting away from option. what wrong i am doing here?

[image]

```
echo '<form action="" method="post" id="pform"><select>';


echo 'Product name: <input type="text" name="pname"><br>';

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
}

echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="pdes" form="pform">';
echo 'Enter product description here...</textarea><br><br>';


echo '</select><input type="submit" name="addp" value="Add this product">'.'</form>';
```

Comment: <select> can't have other inputs, or general text in it.

Comment: then how can i put it in this form?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Be certain your parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you'll have [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting HTML looks something like this:

```
<form ...>
    <select>
        Product name: <input ...>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        ...
        <textarea ...> ... </textarea>
    </select>
    <input>
</form>
```

Which is wrong. `<select>` should only contain `<option>` elements, nothing else. In other words, you should change your code to produce this structure:

```
<form ...>
    Product name: <input ...>
    <select>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        ...
    </select>
    <textarea ...> ... </textarea>
    <input>
</form>
```

So in your case:

```
echo '<form action="" method="post" id="pform">';
echo 'Product name: <input type="text" name="pname"><br>';
echo '<select>';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="pdes" form="pform">';
echo 'Enter product description here...</textarea><br><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="addp" value="Add this product">'.'</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Stirling said the select can contain only `<option>` elements.

```
echo '<select>';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```